# Initialisation in Swift and mutable data

Tags: swift

Watching the WWDC '14 session "Integrating Swift with Objective-C" the speaker at 44'00" wrote two lines of code that I can't understand.

During the initialisation of an object he wrote:

```
Class className; NSObject, NSCoding
{

    let data:NSData
    let type:String

    init(data: NSData, type: String)
    {
        self.data = data.copy() as NSData   // 1
        self.type = type                    // 2

    }

    //...
}
```

I can't understand the rows that I've marked with `//1` and `//2`.
I understand that `copy()` returns an AnyObject type and so NSData typecasting is required. But I can't understand why `self.type` doesn't need this treatment.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

NSData has the mutable subclass NSMutableData that may be passed as well => you have to copy it to be safe.
String is a struct and thus passed by value (copied) so you dont need to copy it.